# Using 360 images for scene background

Tags: image

I'd like to be rendering a scene in which the camera is behind a plane of glass looking at a background scene (a PNG image I provide), and there's rain on the plane of glass. This is what my scene looks like currently:[image]

As you can see, the rain drops are reflecting a lot of the gray background outside the image, but I don't want this. I have 360 camera images that I could use for the background instead, but I'm not sure how to use them in blender. Any advice? Currently my background is just an image on a plane (using "import image as plane"). This is the kind of 360 image I have to use for the background instead:
[image]

Is it possible to use an image like this to create a "wrapped" background, where the whole scene is this 3D background image (instead of just on a plane in front of the camera)?

Answer (score 6):

Use your image as Environment texture for the world.

Instead of color you can choose a texture. Select Environment.

[image]

Then select the image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if there's any way to improve the resolution of the background without feeding in a higher resolution image?

Comment: No, if you care for quality, you need a higher resolution image. You need an image that has enough pixels to fill the screen (and hopefully an image that has a much higher dynamic range).